# Displaying a png image without the background

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png

http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/sunglasses_black.png

I have read the png image in MATLAB using `[X,map,alpha]=imread('...','png')`.
Now I want to place this png image on another image. But I want the background color of the read png not to be shown. In the link I want the sunglasses alone to be shown without the 'white' background (Background is another image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
% Image with alpha channel
[glasses, ~, alpha] = imread('http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/sunglasses_black.png');

% OPTIONAL: Let's rescale it (it's very big!)
glasses = imresize(glasses, 0.1);
alpha = imresize(alpha, 0.1);

% An image of a person (let's put the glasses on the person).
person = imread('http://cinemacao.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Scarlett-CAPA-2.jpg');

% Lets make the alpha MxNx3 (so we can combine it with the RGB channels).
alpha = repmat(alpha, [1 1 3]);

% And convert everything from uint8 to double (to avoid precision issues).
glasses = im2double(glasses);
alpha = im2double(alpha);
person = im2double(person);

% Final image

% Let x,y be the top-left coordinates where we'll put the glasses.
x = 440;
y = 450;

% Let's combine the images.
img3 = person;
img3(y:y+size(glasses,1)-1, x:x+size(glasses,2)-1, :) = ...
    glasses .* alpha + ...
    person(y:y+size(glasses,1)-1, x:x+size(glasses,2)-1, :) .* (1 - alpha);

% An display the result.
imshow(img3);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ohh man thank u so much. Can u explain me whats happening in the last 'combine' section (what is the meaning of '...' and '.*')?

Comment: Sure. The `...` is just a way to tell Matlab the command is broken in multiple lines, and the line following a `...` is part of the current line. The `.*` operator is a dot product operator. It takes two matrices A and B with the same size and results in a matrix C (same size) where every C(i,j) = A(i,j) * B(i,j).

What happens is this: first `img3 = person`. Then, we take the portion of interest of img3 (with the same size as glasses) and replace it by a weighted sum of what was there and the glasses. The `alpha` dictates what "stays person" and `(1 - alpha)` dictates what becomes "glasses".

Answer (score 2):

The alpha channel is opacity, the opposite of transparency.

MATLAB figures support alpha blending via the `AlphaData` property:

```
background = uint8(255*rand(size(alpha)));
imshow(background)
hold on
h = imshow(X);
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha)
```

Result:
[image]

Given another image `Y` and your image `X` with it's alpha data, you can use alpha to generate a blended image. In you case, `alpha` has only the values 0 and 255, but in general there can be levels of opacity. In this simple case, again with noise background, but in color:

```
out = uint8(255*rand(size(X))); % Y
hardMask = repmat(alpha==255,1,1,3);
out(hardMask) = X(hardMask);
imwrite(out,'sunglass_alphaC.png')
```

It's a big image, so I resized the output here:

[image]

If your alpha channel actually had more than two levels of transparency, you could blend with the background:

```
s = double(alpha)/255;
Yout = uint8((bsxfun(@times,1-s,double(Y)) + bsxfun(@times,s,double(X))));
```

For grayscale, `bsxfun` can be replaced with just `.-` (e.g. `s.*double(X)`).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about Matlab, but seems to be that [X,map,alpha] use "alpha" as the alpha channel; alpha channel means level of transparency. (probably you already know this). Also check if the image itself has the alpha channel set. PNG doesn't recognise "white" as alpha channel by default. In this case, go to your favorite "*shop" software to edit the photo (maybe select with magic tool which will be the background, go to select inverse, copy-paste to a new image previously specifying that the background image will be transparency).

Comment: how to interpret this alpha channel data? i have to write some code to copy only the opaque pixels.

Comment: Mmmm dont know exactly what you need, If you have the image in a data structure, just try to get the bytes from the alpha channel. Bytes equals one are 100% transparent, 0 means 0% transparency. Also they could be 256 for 100% and 0 for 0%. Check if there it is a Xor function for imagea, in such a way you could just xor two images to overlap it